# swift segue not passing data from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am having a problem accessing data sent from a `tableViewController` to a `viewController`.

The first file,  tableView Controller is using the following to find the selected row and pass data via a segue:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    var name = self.names[indexPath.row]

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)

        if segue.identifier == "PictureSegue"{
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as pictureViewController

            vc.recvData = name
        }
    }
}
```

The second file (viewController) is trying to read the data and open an alert.  The alert keeps coming up null.  Why is it not receiving the data?

```
class pictureViewController: UIViewController {

var recvData:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if recvData != nil
        {
            if (recvData == "Apapne")
            {
                var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = recvData
                alert.message = recvData
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "no"
            alert.message = "stuff"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()               
            }  
        }
   }
```

Thank you

Comment: can you println("Data before passing is \(name)") and also after passing, println("Data after passing is \(vc.recvData)") and tell me result. So, I can guide you better.

Comment: In `prepareForSegue`, did you access the view of `pictureViewController` before you set `recvData`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't access the property in `viewDidLoad` - it won't be set at that point. Access it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Sir @Paulw11, Where is it documented that we can't access in ViewDidLoad?
I think issue is with data, which is being passed. May be there is no value in name.

Comment: I don't know where it is documented, but it is obvious if you think about the flow.  In `prepareForSegue` you can get a reference to the destination view controller - so it has already been loaded, so `viewDidLoad` has already executed, therefore when you set the property in `prepareForSegue` it is too late to have set it before `viewDidLoad` executes

Comment: But, I have personally fetched value in ViewDidLoad, so I think its not a rule. As I used valued to display on next controller, which are coming with segue from previous controller.

Comment: Well, unless their tableView is full of "null" rows it isn't data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the prepareForSegue method . You have to override it. In your case you're just defining a function inside the tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method which is named prepareForSegue, but you should insert an override method ,instead of your internal function :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue,     sender:AnyObject!) { 
// do preparations 
}
```