# Segue not passing data to ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm trying to pass the data from a TableView so when a cell is pressed, the data on that cell will be transferred to a viewController and display it there, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I tried these posts:

[swift segue not passing data from tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903383/swift-segue-not-passing-data-from-tableview)

[Passing data from tableView to ViewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051631/passing-data-from-tableview-to-viewcontroller-in-swift)

[Pass data through unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622999/pass-data-through-unwind-segue)

But either I get an error that crashes the app, or it doesn't display anything. What I'm trying to do is get a user to comment on a post that another user posted, so I'm trying to get the info from the post to display it in detail, but that's where I'm having trouble. This is the function I'm using to pass the data from the table view:

```
func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PFObject {
    return self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "lookPosts"){
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewContoller
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath! = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        VC.post = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as PFObject
    }
}
```

and this is the class of the DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailViewContoller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

    var post: PFObject?
    var commentView: UITextView?
    var footerView: UIView?
    var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    var comments: [String]?
    let FOOTERHEIGHT : CGFloat = 50;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        commentTableView.delegate = self

        /* Setup the keyboard notifications */
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        //gets the current user username
        usernameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()!.username as String?

        if(post?.objectForKey("comments") != nil) {
            comments = post?.objectForKey("comments") as? [String]
        }

        println(post)
        println(post?.objectForKey("content"))
        //self.postTextView.text = post?.objectForKey("content") as? String
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.postTextView.text = post?.objectForKey("content") as? String
        println(postTextView.text)
    }


    func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

        var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40


        var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat

        var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
        self.commentTableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    }

    func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        self.commentTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = comments?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = commentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
        cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if self.footerView != nil {
            return self.footerView!.bounds.height
        }
        return FOOTERHEIGHT
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: commentTableView.bounds.width, height: FOOTERHEIGHT))
        footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 243.0/255, green: 243.0/255, blue: 243.0/255, alpha: 1)
        commentView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: commentTableView.bounds.width - 80 , height: 40))
        commentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        commentView?.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
        commentView?.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        commentView?.scrollsToTop = false

        footerView?.addSubview(commentView!)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: commentTableView.bounds.width - 65, y: 10, width: 60 , height: 30))
        button.setTitle("Reply", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:  0/0.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 204/255.0, alpha: 100.0/100.0)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.addTarget(self, action: "reply", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        footerView?.addSubview(button)
        commentView?.delegate = self
        return footerView
    }


    //Hide keyboard after touching background
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //remaining characters
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

        if (text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }

    func reply() {
        post?.addObject(commentView!.text, forKey: "comments")
        post?.saveInBackground()
        if let tmpText = commentView?.text {
            comments?.append(tmpText)
        }
        commentView?.text = ""
        println(comments?.count)
        self.commentView?.resignFirstResponder()
        self.commentTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So my question here is: Is there another way of passing the data? or what am I doing wrong that the data is not passing?

Comment: Have you checked the name of your segue and made sure the block of code inside the if clause in `prepareForSegue` is running?

Comment: @vigneshv the way I have it let `VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewContoller` makes the app crash, I have to change it to: `if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewContoller {}` but once I change it to that, it doesn't display the data

Comment: well it shouldn't crash the app. It means that the casting failed, so no data is sent. Make sure you're not pushing a navigation controller in this segue, this should be fairly easy to debug.

Comment: Like FruitAddict said, this is probably due to the fact that your `destinationViewController` is not a `DetailViewController`, in addition to FruitAddict suggested, make sure your ViewController in storyboard is a subclass of `DetailViewController`.

Comment: The segue is going from the tableView Cell, to a ViewController, and `DetailViewController` is just the name of the class, so it's a subclass of `UIViewController`

Comment: That's not the point. Make sure that the `lookPosts` segue poiints to the DetailsViewController, not something like it's wrapping navigation controller. Also make sure that this view has its class set correctly in the storyboard.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint before your typecast to `DetailViewController` and check what `segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(DetailViewController)` returns?

Comment: Before? or at the cast? @vigneshv

Comment: At the cast. Make sure the line of code doesn't run.

Comment: I added the breaking point, but I'm not sure what to look at. Sorry I'm still new to swift and Xcode @vigneshv

Comment: Go to the debugger and type `segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(DetailViewController)`

Comment: I checked, and the data being passed, it's printed out as nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88588/discussion-between-vigneshv-and-bruno-recillas).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to acheive that:

If your data is not large then you can use `NSUserDefaults` for that.

First store your data to memory:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(yourObject, forKey: "yourKey")
```

Read your data from memory in another viewController:

```
let yourObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") as! PFObject
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't belive it's large since I just want to pass the data of the cell the user is clicking, so I guess this would work, but where do I apply this? Inside the `prepareForSegue` function?

Comment: You can store your object in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: This will store it app-wide FYI, and you could store the data in the `prepareForSegue`. Its also persistent, so even if the user quits the app, the data will still be stored.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni using it this way I wouldn't need to perform the segue function right?

Comment: Could I save it at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: No you can't because you need index when you press any row in your `tableView`.

Comment: Okay so I created a new tableView function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and I added this inside:
`let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cell.postTextView.text, forKey: "content")`

and In the `DetailViewController` class I added this to `viewWillAppear` : `let yourObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("content") as! PFObject
        self.postTextView.text = yourObject.objectForKey("content") as? String` but it crashed. Did I do wrong